# Why won't masterplan let me add traits/powers to Creature Templates?

Tags: dnd-4e, masterplan

Whenever I try to do so, the program does nothing. I can add powers and traits to monsters, just not to creature templates.

This is in the libraries menu of Masterplan.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't have experience with the software, but it doesn't sound like a person would know where to start to replicate your problem.

Comment: Which Version of Masterplan are you using?  Are you using any Add-ins?

Comment: I am having the same problem, ver 11.11. This is the first bug I have encountered since using the program. No add-ins, just the standard program. Just as with the poster I can add powers/traits to creatures but not to templates. Auras/tactics work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In short : **It's a bug, or a missing feature if you will**.

You are supposed to be able to, but the software itself simply have some crossed wires in it's code, and doesn't give you any interface to apply these.

Funny enough, if you are feeling bold, you can pry open the files in a good binary editor, and force-apply traits to the creature templates. So in essence, the application can handle it, but the interface given is unable to show.

I have reported this to the developers themselves, since they are the ones that can functionally fix this.

My guess is that this will be applied eventually, but since there are many other bugs in Masterplan, they propably need to prioritize.